# Convert continuous signal into discrete in Knime

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization, data-mining, knime

I have predicted the Alarm line using Linear Regression and it seems quite convincing. However, i need to output in discrete values(As shown in Screenshot)
[image: Screenshot]
**Figure Description**
Predicted Alarm : * Sky Blue*
Real Alarm : *Green*

**My Approach**

I have tried to smooth the signal using Moving Average(Simple exponential), and also tried to smooth the signal by using ggplot2, still could not achieve the requirement.

**Tools Used**

Knime and R studio

**Question**

*1.* Suggestion on alternate method to convert continuous output to discreet ?

Suggestion Appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Moving Average does not produce discrete values. You need to use a threshold system (like for example through a Rule Engine node in KNIME) or a binning system (like through one of the many Binner nodes in KNIME). I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Rosaria. I am trying to define rules to make it discrete , however difficult to conclude